# Keep XML namespaces after split or grep

Tags: xml, perl

I have a huge xml-file (several GB) which I can split with xml_split or I can extract the relevant subbnode with xml_grep. I run out of RAM if I try to read the whole XML.

But when I try to parse one of the splitted files, or the grep:ed file, I get the error "Namespace prefix xx on yy is not defined" thousands of times.

Is there a way to copy the namespace-definition from the original file to the splitted or grep:ed files? Or have I misunderstood the errors?

I'm very new to XML and I find XML::TWIG useful. Here is the grep-command I use:

```
xml_grep --root 'SubInformation' --cond 'SubInformationName[string()="Blah"]' Infile.xml > Outfile.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which tool are you using to parse the result of the split (or the grep)? `xmllint` (from `libxml2`) complains, but `xmlwf` (from `expat`) doesn't. So I think any expat-based tool would be ok with the XML, but not libxml2-based ones.

It looks like `xml_split` and `xml_grep` could declare the namespaces though. At least it should be an option. I'll have a look at it.

In the meantime, here is a quick'n dirty way to post-process the result you get with `xml_grep`:

```
xml_grep --root 'SubInformation' --cond 'SubInformationName[string()="Blah"]' Infile.xml | perl -MXML::Twig -e'XML::Twig->new( start_tag_handlers => { xml_grep => sub { $_->set_att( "xmlns:m" => "http://m.org") }, SubInformation => sub { $_->flush } })->parse( \*STDIN)' > Outfile.xml
```

replace `xmlns:m` and `"http://m.org"` with the appropriate values.

Let me think of a way to do this in a generic way for the result of `xml_split`. Can I assume that the namespace declarations are not too tricky (ie that the prefix(es) are declared just once)?

**Edit**: Here is a way to add the namespace declarations to the files resulting from `xml_split`, call it as `add_ns Infile` after you have run `xml_split` on Infile.xml:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $root= shift @ARGV;

my( $base, @files)= sort glob( "$root-*.xml");

my %ns= ns_for_file( $base);

foreach my $file (@files)
  { add_ns( $file, %ns); }


sub ns_for_file
  { my( $base)= @_;
    my %ns;
    XML::Twig->new( start_tag_handlers
      # get namespace declarations from the root and bail
      => { 'level(0)' => sub { %ns= ns_for_tag( $_); 
                               $_[0]->finish_now(); 
                             } 
         },
                  )
             ->parsefile( $base);
    return %ns;
  }

# get all namespace declarations from the root element
sub ns_for_tag
  { my( $e)= @_;
    return map { $_ => $e->att( $_) if m{^xmlns:} } $e->att_names;
  }

sub add_ns
  { my( $file, %ns)= @_;
     XML::Twig->new( start_tag_handlers => { 'level(0)' => sub { $_->set_att( %ns); } },
                     twig_handlers => { _all_ => sub { $_->flush; } },
                     keep_spaces => 1,
                   )
              ->parsefile_inplace( $file);
```

}

Comment: I use libxml2... Or actually a wrapper for libxml2 in "R" (statistical language). It would be really great if splitted files can be parsed by libxml2. And thanks for the great tool by the way!

Comment: Thanks, testing now. When I run grep xmlns on the original file I see 5 different xmlns:xx="abc123", was that waht you refered to with prefixes declared just once? Each of the 5 is only listed onec though.

Comment: are the namespace declarations all on the root element?

Comment: I added a solution for `xml_split`. The only assumption it makes is that the namespace declarations are on the root of the original document. If that's not the case, let me know, it would be a little more complicated (and much slower I think)

Answer (score 0):

To process large XML files, you can also use a pull parser. See [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aReader).